# How can I load color index of each cell in a range into an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to dump range(A1:A30)into an array. It works fine when I am extracting  the cell value for the range.

```
 aM = Sheet2.Range("A1:A30").Value
```

But, I require the Color Index of each cell in that range.I know, I can get this done by looping through each cell in that range. For efficiency purpose I don't want to use the looping option.

Can I achieve this by using the following code/alternative method?

```
Dim aM() As Variant
aM = Sheet2.Range("A1:A30").Interior.ColorIndex
For i = LBound(aM) To UBound(aM)
    Debug.Print aM(i, 1)
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can I achieve this by using the following code/alternative method?*

### [image]

You have to loop. Even if it was possible to do it like this `am = Range.Interior.ColorIndex` there would be a hidden loop implemented behind it. In `aM = Sheet2.Range("A1:A30").Value` there is also a loop implemented, you just do not see it.

In general, loading 300K colors takes 2 seconds with me:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim aM(300000)      As Long

    For i = LBound(aM) To UBound(aM)
        aM(i) = Cells(i + 1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't technically *have* to loop - you could do it with a defined name and formulas in an adjacent column, but it wouldn't save you any real time!

Comment: Thanks mate... I will stick with the looping... Just needed your comments on this... I am trying to get the data onto an array and then further use dictionary to manipulate the data further... Is this a good way to go about it or I am over complicating it and just the get the data onto the dictionary directly?

Comment: @JaspalLabana - dictionary is quite a bad idea, because if it used the correct way it should not have the same values twice. And in any case, you would probably have twice the same color. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table (a.k.a. Dictionary)

Comment: @Rory - and if you use only 1 processor in Excel the formulas would be executed one after the other (but really fast, you will not even notice it). Which is technically a loop. But this is too much into details :)

Comment: @Vityata I think it's pretty clear that the meaning was a loop in the VBA though! ;)

Comment: @Rory - absolutely :) But in the context of my answer, I mention the "hidden loop" behind assigning an Array to Range.

Comment: @Vitayata - If this is with reference to Key, I know it needs to be unique. In terms of color this would be the value. Say, Key = 1.1e.1 and value = Color index for the cell... :-)

Comment: The looping is fine. Looping takes no time at all, it's repetitively accessing the range object that takes time. It's why we pull all the range values into an array before working with them.